# outputing a 2-column PHP/MySQL Dropdown menu request

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Hope you can help me....

I have a dropdown menu that works fine when requesting from a single column as follows:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

echo "<form action=\"$t\" method=\"post\">";

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT y FROM $z") or die("Db temp. not available");

    echo "<select name=dropdown>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    echo "<option value=\"".$hy."\">".$hy."</option>";

    }

    echo "</select>";

    echo "<input value=\"SORT\" name=\"submit\">";

    echo "</form>";

    }

    else {

    $dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);

    $d = "DATE_FORMAT( date,'%d/%m/%Y' )as date";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * , $d FROM $z WHERE y='$dropdown'  ORDER BY date DESC");
```

when I try to add a extra column (as below), using the same output methods, the request is not recognized---Zero errors are shown and all variables  can be echoed at the appropriate places.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "<form action=\"$t\" method=\"post\" >";


    $query="SELECT DISTINCT x, y FROM $z ORDER BY x";

    echo "<dd><select name=dropdown>";

    if ($result = mysql_query($query))
    {
    $numofrows = mysql_num_rows($result);   
    for($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 


            if($row['y']=="HOTTEST"){
            echo "<option  value=\"" . $i . "\">" .$hy. "------------" .$hx. "</option>";    }      
            elseif($row['y']=="GRADUAL"){
            echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }        
            elseif($row['y']=="TOP-Seller"){
            echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }        
            elseif($row['y']=="HOT-Seller"){
            echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }
            else {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" .$hy. "----------" .$hx. "</option>";    } 

        }
    }
            else    {

        print "Could not retrieve the data because: 1' . mysql_error() . '";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<input  type=\"submit\" value=\"SORT\" name=\"submit\">";

    echo "</form>";
    }

    else     {


    $dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);

    $d = "DATE_FORMAT( date,'%d/%m/%Y' )as date";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * , $d FROM $z WHERE y='$dropdown'  ORDER BY date DESC");
```

I hope you can shed some light into the matter for me.

Thanks
Sammy

Comment: Reformat this using a stylesheet, please. This is psychotic to look at.

Comment: :O I cant believe my eyes | http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Comment: please remove the style tags - they don't make a difference in this sample. Also, instead of adding the htmlspecialchars to every option, set $y = htmlspecialchars($row['yyyyy']) and similarly $x, much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry guys...copied this into notepad to edit it first....hope you can now help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work

```
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    $numofrows = mysql_num_rows($result);   
    for($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
        if (!mysql_data_seek($result, $i))   //add this line
           continue; //add this line

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

        ........

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alon...no change unfortunately

Comment: Can anyone kindly elaborate on the above 'mysql_data_seek' please...does this check for entries and if found continues, or?

Comment: IThe actual dropdown list is showing the data of both colums...I just cant print the clicked results :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is very difficult to debug this, since I cannot create the same conditions as in your server. However, your code had alot of syntax issues. I cleared them up for you.. Either it starts working or at least some smarter person then me can debug it further.

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown option {
    height: 22px; 
    width: 255px;
    margin-bottom: 3px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #00FF00; /* This also is the default color */
}
.dropdown .hottest {background-color: #FF020D;}
.dropdown .gradual {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
.dropdown .top-seller {background-color: #FFFF00;}
.dropdown .hot-seller {background-color: orange;}
```

**PHP:**

```
// Lets get rid of the notices, as you dont need them for this script
// error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Understanding that this is a sorting dropdown, then we are going to display this all the time:
if ($results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE ORDER BY COL_X')) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post"><select name="dropdown" class="dropdown">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

        $row_y = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['COL_Y']);
        $row_x = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['COL_X']);

        if ($row['COL_Y'] == "HOTTEST") {
            echo '<option  value="' . $row['COL_Y'] . '-|-' . $row['COL_X'] . '" class="hottest">' . $row_y . '------------' . $row_x . '</option>';
        } elseif ($row['COL_Y'] == "GRADUAL") {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['COL_Y'] . '-|-' . $row['COL_X'] . '" class="gradual">' . $row_y . '------------' . $row_x . '</option>';
        } elseif ($row['COL_Y'] == "TOP-Seller") {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['COL_Y'] . '-|-' . $row['COL_X'] . '" class="top-seller">' . $row_y . '------------' . $row_x . '</option>';
        } elseif ($row['COL_Y'] == "HOT-Seller") {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['COL_Y'] . '-|-' . $row['COL_X'] . '" class="hot-seller">' . $row_y . '------------' . $row_x . '</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['COL_Y'] . '-|-' . $row['COL_X'] . '">' . $row_y . '------------' . $row_x . '</option>';
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($results);
    echo '</select><input type="submit" value="SORT" name="submit"></form>';
} else {
    print 'Could not retrieve the data because: ' . mysql_error();
}

// And when the form has been submitted, then use this:
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    list($post_col_y, $post_col_x) = explode('-|-', $_POST['dropdown']);
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS `date` FROM $w_table WHERE `COL_Y` = '$post_col_y' AND `COL_X` = '$post_col_x' ORDER BY `date` DESC"); 
} else {
    // However, you also need to show some data without any sorting:
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS `date` FROM $w_table ORDER BY `date` DESC");
}
```

**EDIT 6** Understanding that COL_Y is the rating and COL_X is the category, and that you want both of this criteria to be posted and then used in the query. This is script should do the trick now. However, there might come an issue. Because your COL_Y and COL_X values can have special characters..hence the htmlspecialchars(). However, you cant htmlspecialchars the raw data in the options value.. or it wont match in the query.

**EDIT 5** I started realizing before, but I was waiting for your feedback. Now that I have seen the example of what you are trying to do, I updated the answer. I'm pretty confident that this will work. You just have to replace the terms with your own parameters (EXAMPLE_TABLE, COL_Y, COL_X). Also, if you know exactly what [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) does in mysql, then you should probably add it back..

**EDIT 4** Ok, as I checked your very first revision.. You have nerfed your code down so much, that it lost the original point and did not make any sense. I used your very first revision on this edit. I added the CSS part as well, so the code would make sense again.. And also, so you could see how CSS works.. I added the `htmlspecialchars()` parts back again, because otherwise your code makes no sense. Changed the mysql error printing location in relation to `<select>` starting and ending. I also changed the terms, because they didn't make much sense before. The terms are:

- **EXAMPLE_TABLE** - Your only table in this code, from where all the data is being pulled.
- **COL_Y** - Column inside the **EXAMPLE_TABLE**, it appears to be some sort of rating
- **COL_X** - Second column in this hole code. The output of this column is unknown.

**EDIT 3** I removed `DISTINCT x, y` and replaced with `*`. Based on the comments and debugging progress, this might be confusing things.

**EDIT 2** I removed `$hy` and `$hx`, because if you are basing your scripts functionality on them. Then it cant possible work, as these variables don't get set anywhere in this script.

**EDIT** I edited the code slightly, as I started to realize what is going on (I'm very tired.) Basically, why did you use `for()` for mysql result loop? It made no sense what so ever, except that you wanted to use the `$i` count. I changed that part, it theory this should work..

You basically should give us the error messages, other variables, the mysql table scheme and any other information.. Why not explain, what for are you creating this script etc..

**NOTES**

- Why are you quoting this string? `echo "<input  type=\"submit\" value=\"SORT\" name=\"submit\">";` You can actually use `'`: `echo '<input type="submit" ..`
- The very very last `else` doesn't get closed! Neither does the `isset($_POST['submit']`
- `!isset($_POST['submit'])` ?!? Did you mean `empty($_POST['submit'])`?
- Also, the `!isset($_POST['submit'])` part doesn't make much sense. Usually, the posting script is before the form.. Anyways, I changed it alot.. Sorry, but this makes more sense in my head.
- You don't need to end quotes like this, if you using double-quotes: `echo "<div class=\"" . $class . "\" />";` You can do it like this: `echo "<div class=\"$class\" />";`
- `print "Could ... 1' . mysql_error() . '";` cannot possible work. You cannot end double quotes with single quotes...?!
- Why are your variables names so short? `$z`, `$hy` and `$hx` etc.. You always have to code, with the idea at the back of your head.. that some other developer someday must ready your code.. Even you! Yeah, right now you remember, what is what.. But In 5 months, with many new projects behind you, you will not remember what `$hx` meant. Also, as you can see, it is very hard to help you right now..

Comment: @all of you great guys....I'm tired too, it's 09:00am here and I've been at this now for 2 days......I'll try everything later today with, hopefully a fresh head ;) Thanks Guys...I'll be back

Comment: @Kalle... I tried ALL your variations and the menu does show up but the table doesn't. It appears that the second table "X" is for whatever reason, not being carried over and hence producing 0 rows. Also KALLE...Thanks for lessons and the unexpected $ends were simply because I was only asking about the dropdown.list..not the rest but I'll keep that in mind the next time I post a query. 

Maybe someone has an idea how to echo these two tables via the, it would certainly make my day :)
It's hard to explain everything in 600 characters :(
Thanks
SammyJ

Comment: @SammyJ: Table X? There is only one table: $z. Did you mean those `SELECT DISTINCT x, y FROM $z`. Those are columns not tables. Also, your terms and etc in your question are very unclear. And you don't have enough rep. to come to chat.. Well, lets try to make things little bit clearer. You want to return data, from one tables two columns? However, let me point out, that you are not using the `$row['x']` anywhere. So on what are you basing that its not displaying correct?

Comment: I meant column...so busy trying to figure out how to format text in here and cram things into 600 characters that the point doesn't come accross! I think I'll leave it. X and Y are columns and should show in ONE MENU but both sorted results should should show in the table. Column X is shown as **$hx** = 'htmlspeaclchars($row['x']'

Comment: Based only on this script and query, the $hx doesn't get set anywhere. So there for you cannot possible see it. Also, there is no table (except the DB table) in this script, there is only select and submit elements, wrapped in a form. No table. Check the edited answer.

Comment: KALLE!.....I was asked to remove 'htmlspeaclchars($row['x']' and replace it with a variable for BETTER READING at the beginnning of this post, so simply imagin that it is set.

Comment: I think I understand what the problem is...The datebase has to be constructed in a manner that it accepts the above request. I simply have the "id" as PK and the other columns are just "int" for prices and varchar for descriptions and urls. So I imagine they need some kind of additional index for the cross-referencing. Am I thinking i correctly or just confusing the matter?

Comment: Don't remove important parts of the code like `htmlspeaclchars($row['x']`, because that will make things much more confusing. You were asked to remove the `style=""` styling, because firstly, it was ugly to look at and also totally irrelevant. Anyways, try the code now after **EDIT 3**.

Comment: And now check **EDIT 4** you only had to remove the styling, but you took out so much important code and also changed variables so much, that they are not logic and bring up another set of syntax problems. I checked your first revision and added some important things back.. Also added the CSS and created new terms, so you could explain your case better, based on those terms. And naturally, yes, DB should be constructed in the way, that standard mysql query can output your data.

Comment: Ok based on the comment below.. What is the actual problem and what are you trying to do? Im currently not looking for an error in the code, but trying to understand the point. This script will produce 1 select dropdown, from 1 table `EXAMPLE_TABLE` that has 2 colums `COL_Y` and `COL_X`. If `COL_Y` matches your given variable, then it will add a class to the `select option`. `option` will display in the format: `COL_Y------------COL_X`. Or are you having problems with posting the select menu? Can you please make a screenshot in your phpmyadmin of the `EXAPLE_TABLE`

Comment: can I reach you per mail KALLE, it would be so much easier if you could see what's happening(or not happening).I could give you 2 examples..one working and one not working. I can't post my site in here

Comment: just sent you a mail ...THANKS :)

Comment: Well..I cant use the order of entries as you put them...the dropdown always has to be BELOW the form and if `($_POST['submit'])` always give the message "**Undefined index: submit**"--I have to use `if (!isset($_POST['Submit']))`.....this is a `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` post so the dropdown has to be after the form

Answer (score 0):

I think i understant your problem. try this:

```
     if($row['y']=="HOTTEST"){
        echo "<option  value=\"" . $row['y'] . "\">" .$hy. "------------" .$hx. "</option>";    }      
        elseif($row['y']=="GRADUAL"){
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['y'] . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }        
        elseif($row['y']=="TOP-Seller"){
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['y'] . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }        
        elseif($row['y']=="HOT-Seller"){
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['y'] . "\">" .$hy. "-----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }
        else {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['y'] . "\">" .$hy. "----------" .$hx. "</option>";    }
```

Comment: @Alon...I mentioned above that the menu is showing the two colums 'X' and 'Y' but when I click on them with your method, ALL products in the 'X' column are showing up but not as shown in the dropdown-list - as seperated categories. E.G.
 
> "Y"----------"X" 
> HOTTEST--------CARS 
> HOTTEST--------TV'S 
> HOTTEST--------Bananas  
> `` 
> TOP-Seller-----CARS 
> TOP-Seller-----TV'S 
> TOP-Seller-----Carrots 

allthough they are shown seperated in the dropdown...I still receive EVERY category related to the HOTTEST even though I clicked only on HOTTEST CARS.